# Principles of counting

Tags: combinatorics

I am currently studying permutations, combinations and counting principles, and I face difficulty in the exponent questions. To make it clear, let me give an example,
"In how many ways can six different rings be worn in four fingers?" I get confused in these sums on whether to use $4^6$ or $6^4$. Could somebody please explain the situation, so that I can tackle these kinds of questions?

Comment: I'd say neither, since the order of  the rings on any fixed finger matters (i.e. putting $r_1$ on a given finger followed by $r_2$ on the same finger is not the same as putting those two on the same finger in the opposite order).  If you only had one finger, I'd say the answer was $6!=720$.

Comment: If you declared that the order on each finger did not matter (though, really, it should) then each ring has $4$ choices and as each choice can be made independently we get $6$ factors of $4$, or $4^6$.  If you get confused, try changing the numbers.  If you had only one ring, the answer would be $4$, not $6$.

Comment: @Anne:  Assume one ring worn on one finger, then the choice is $6^4$.

Comment: If you add another ring, it can go on one of the four fingers, multiplying the count by $4,$ assuming we state that the order of the rings on the fingers doesn't matter. If you add another finger, you essentially have to start the count all over again.

Comment: @lulu Oh yes, actually in the answer of the question, it was given 4^6 and I completely forgot about the order thing (which now makes me think the question was incomplete since they even mentioned the rings to be different.) The method of changing the numbers clears my confusion. Thank You!

Comment: Glad to have helped.  Note that the problem should also specify whether or not you are required to wear all $6$ rings.  In my comments, I have assumed that requirement, but it is not stated anywhere.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Yes now I realized my mistake. Thank you for helping!

Comment: @lulu Yes, it should have mentioned that, and the order thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that rings and fingers question you can use the so called "stars and bars" method. Let there be $m$ rings to be put to $n$ fingers. Think of a possible arrangements as a permutation of $n-1$ **gaps of fingers** (these are the "bars") and $m$ **rings** ("stars"). Now, the gaps of fingers aren't distinct (...well they are but they are dictated by the permutation so the bar-symbols for them aren't distinct), so we need to divide by $(n-1)!$ and the answer is

$$\frac{(m+n-1)!}{(n-1)!}$$

This is assuming the rings are distinguishable. If they aren't, we also divide by $m!$ and in fact have the usual stars and bars answer $m+n-1 \choose m$.

Comment: I did not know this method before. I will work on it. Thank you!

Comment: This is alternate and much faster method. Both this and my second method will give correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

> I am currently studying $\ldots$ counting principles, and I face difficulty in $\ldots$ Could somebody please explain the situation, so that I can tackle these kinds of questions?

Basic combinatorics is about the concept of putting **objects** into **boxes**. In any question first ask yourself, what are the *boxes* and what are the *objects*. Here fingers serve as boxes and rings are the objects.

Now the big idea is : **you have to ask *each object* which *box* it wants to go into**. If you ask *each box* which *objects* it will take, the solution may become very complicated or go very wrong.

For illustration, consider the answer $6^4 = 6 \times 6 \times 6 \times 6$ : it means, the first box (finger) chose exactly one object (one ring) out of six, although we can put more than one ring on a finger. Now the second box should have only $5$ choices available so doing $6 \times 6 \times \ldots$ is also incorrect. But even if you do $6 \times 5 \times 4 \times 3$, you will realize that only $4$ objects are being put into the boxes, which is again wrong.

Now if we ask each object or ring which box or finger it wants to go to, each ring has $4$ choices so six rings can make $4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 $ $\times 4 \times 4 = 4^6$ choices. In this manner we see that all six rings are being properly distributed among four fingers, each finger is now able to take more than one ring.

---

I wrote the above answer keeping multiplication principle and given book answer $4^6$ in mind, but that assumes the condition that ordering of rings on each finger does not matter. If we take ordering into account, the correct solution will go as following :

First enumerate the cases of how many rings are on each finger. These are partitions of $6$ into $4$ parts:
$$(6,0,0,0), (5,1,0,0), (4,2,0,0), (3,3,0,0), (4,1,1,0), (3,2,1,0), (2,2,2,0), (3,1,1,1), (2,2,1,1)$$

For example, the case $(4,2,0,0)$ means some two of the four fingers have $4$ rings and $2$ rings. Now one arranges the rings according to above distributions. I will leave the remaining calculation for the OP.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot of sense now. I was, in a way, confused in whom to ask, the box or the object! Thank you.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Yes I realized this after your comment. I have fixed the solution. Either way I think the concept of boxes and objects will be useful to the OP, who I presume is in early stages of learning Combinatorics.

Answer (score 0):

Exponentiation in counting problems usually comes from the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). So just make sure you understand the multiplication principle and remember the meaning of exponentiation, e.g. $2^5=2\times2\times2\times2\times2$.

Answer (score -3):

For each finger there are $6$ choices. And since there are $4$ fingers, the number of different choices would be $6^4$.

Comment: This is exactly wrong. For each ring, it can go on one of four fingers. A finger can have more than one ring. (This ignores why neither number is correct, since order of the multiple rings on a finger matters, unless the problem states otherwise.)

Comment: Please delete this inaccurate post.